# What is the correct syntax for signing Inno Setup files?

Tags: inno-setup

I am trying to sign my Inno Setup file. I get an exit error 0x1 ?? Here is the line I am using to configure the sign tool in Inno:

```
"c:\Digital certificate\signtool.exe" sign/a/t  http://timestamp.digicert.com  / f "c:\Digital cerificate\mycertificate.pfx"/p "mypassword"/d "C:\Flash projects\flash projects 2022\Reset\inno\reset setup file\ResetSetup.exe" $f
```

Is the syntax OK? I am not sure about the use of quotations when specifying file names, also the `$f` at the end of the command line? Do I need it?

Any links / examples to how to configure the signtool would be appreciated.

Comment: As it is your command line is odd because you have `/ f` (a space with your `/f` switch. But see my answer for how I sign the executable when compiling the installer with Inno Setup.

Comment: I simplified your question as you were asking several questions - which is frowned upon really. Your "Title Question" is good enough and to the point. All the other quests were just your "thinking out loud" IMHO. :)

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: Thanks, Andrew, I have discovered the ksign utility which allows me to sign the inno generated setup file. I will try your suggestions . Many thanks to you and other commenters.

Answer (score 1):

In Inno Setup I configure the Sign Tools:

[image]

> `SignTool="C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x64\signtool.exe" sign $p`

You would have to qualify the path to the `signtool` executable on your PC.

Then, in my script I have some definitions:

```
; SignTool parameters
#define SignedDesc "$qAppName$q"
#define SignedPfx "$qd:\My Certificate\2021\My Certificate.pfx$q"
#define SignedTimeStamp "$qhttp://timestamp.digicert.com$q"
;define SignedTimeStamp "$qhttp://timestamp.comodoca.com/authenticode$q"
;#define SignedTimeStamp "$qhttp://timestamp.globalsign.com/scripts/timestamp.dll$q"
;#define SignedTimeStamp "$qhttp://tsa.starfieldtech.com$q"
;#define SignedTimeStamp "$qhttp://timestamp.sectigo.com$q"
; The last server needs 15 seconds delay.
#define SignedPw "$qabc1234$q"
```

Adjust the values as required for your application etc..

In the `[Setup]` section ([read more](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setup_signtool.htm)):

```
SignedUninstaller=yes
SignTool=SignTool /d {#SignedDesc} /du $q{#AppURL}$q /f {#SignedPfx} /p {#SignedPw} /t {#SignedTimeStamp} /v $f
SignToolRunMinimized=yes
SignToolMinimumTimeBetween=5000
```

In the `[Files]` section make sure you use either `sign` or `signonce`. Eg:

```
Source: "AppRestarter.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: IgnoreVersion signonce
```